# CSS Only applying when I write it twice

Tags: html, css

I've encountered a strange problem. I have 3 divs named #page1, #page2, and #page3. I've applied css styles to them, though the #page1 id is only applying when I write it out twice.

Eg,

```
#page1{
background-color:rgb(27, 163, 156);
height: 100vh;
}
```

Does not apply the class, though if I add it again like:

```
#page1{
background-color:rgb(27, 163, 156);
height: 100vh;
}

#page1{
    background-color:rgb(27, 163, 156);
    height: 100vh;
}
```

then it works fine, at first I thought I had misspelled something though it's working when copying and pasting this.

Here is the full html and css, I can't see what's causing this, thanks for the comments!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>1 page scroll test</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page1"></div>
    <div id="page2"></div>
    <div id="page3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}

#page1{
    background-color:rgb(27, 163, 156);
    height: 100vh;
}

#page2{
    background-color:rgb(134, 226, 213);
    height: 100vh;
}

#page3{
    background-color:rgb(101, 198, 187);
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Provide html code ... !

Comment: this is not a class actually, but styles, but I see what you mean. That said, I see no reason why. Can you narrow your code down and still reproduce this behaviour in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: provide code to get answer.

Comment: I do not think this your CSS or HTML is wrong. I think the answer lies more in your environment. In which browser do you check your website? Does the other pages have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing `<style>` tag. In addition the style should be either in the `head` section or in the `body` section.

Checkout [**this DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/qenucaluqi/1/)

Comment: But you don't put style tags in CSS files. The second part of his code is a separate CSS file named style.css, apparently.

Comment: Css file is another story, like that you don't place `<script>` tag in `js` file. the linking tag define it for the browser to deal with it like a css. but as you regarded the browser will consider it a text.

Answer (score 0):

I predict that if you examine your CSS you will see an error **before** your rule, which is causing CSS to swallow the rule. Once the rule in error is passed over, then the next rule (your duplicate) is processed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok bit of a weird one, tried it on jfiddle and it worked fine so I re-wrote it exactly the same to a new css/html file and it is working fine now, thanks for the comments guys much appreciated!